# Facing this issue in nodemailer using gmail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Getting below error for  nodemailer using gmail

```
{ [Error: Invalid login]

code: 'EAUTH',
response: '534-5.7.14 `<https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1`
&plt=AKgnsbvTx\n534-5.7.14 9r1Ek0CXdMUxJ7ZxkXvj1zoJ497Hd6x0DdN9dIQAMoLxjCtxDWIea
bq8F8vX7cPieMmQXc\n534-5.7.14 -Iy52ZHvmujVE3-i8yvxiz3qCk77DlXg6AmXGKnle1jksnA5km
lV1NufScIVpt14Y2B8g4\n534-5.7.14 J-2HLuRAm2PAw5O3I95RJB1Deb1ALAk_ma8SgYZ0u9D2MYu
PauDUG_Yjazb7tOcrzA39Te\n534-5.7.14 5IcpUApVo7DiXt4xlrn5ylX5qk58> Please log in
via your web browser and\n534-5.7.14 then try again.\n534-5.7.14 Learn more at
n534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 77sm13524842wml.20 - g
smtp', 
responseCode: 534 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Gmail blocks IP addresses from AWS by default.

After logging into gmail locally, visit the following URL.

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha